# Python Pandas: How to Handle 'Error tokenizing data' When Downloading CSV files using 'For' Loop?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Python - Error tokenizing data in For loop to download multiple CSV files

I am following along with a data modelling project online and am having trouble downloading the necessary data. The author created a For loop to allow for the quick downloading of multiple csv files. When I copied this code I got the following error:

Error
`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 6`

This is the code I used:

Code

```
leagues_short=['SP1', 'D1', 'E0', 'I1'] #spanish league, bundesliga, prem, serie a
dict_historical_data = {}

for league in leagues_short:
    frames = []
    for i in range(15, 21):
        df = pd.read_csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/"+str(i)+str(i+1)+"/"+league+".csv")
        df = df[['Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'Full time home goals', 'Full time away goals']] # choose any column you want
        df = df.rename(columns={'Full time home goals': 'HomeGoals', 'Full time away goals': 'AwayGoals'})
        df = df.assign(Season=i)
        frames.append(df)
    df_historical_data = pd.concat(frames)
    dict_historical_data[league] = df_historical_data
```

[Original data available from here](https://github.com/ifrankandrade/football-games-predictions/blob/main/Football%20Games%20Predictions.ipynb)

I would greatly appreciate help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1). Try instead of constructing the file name during reading data (exactly 6 fields as in the error) to do it BEFORE and pass futher 1 string.

2). If it doesn't help - you'd better provide the FULL error message, not just 1 row.